# Trouble in finding limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let's consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ defined as follows: 
 $f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
2n^2x,  & \text{$0\le x \le \frac{1}{2n}$} \\
2n-2n^2x, & \text{$\frac{1}{2n}\le x\le \frac{1}{n}$}\\
0,  & \frac{1}{n}\le x\le 1 
\end{cases} \tag{1}$ 
Intuitively, it seems  from (1) that as $n \to \infty, 1/n, 1/2n $ tend to $0$ hence eventually for large enough n, we end up with $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x \gt 0.$ I am trying to write a formal proof of it. 
So I have to show that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $|f_n(x)-0|\lt \epsilon \tag{2}$  
(2) should be correct for every definition of $f_n(x)$ in (1). If I take $f_n(x)=2n^2 x $ then clearly $|f_n(x)|=2n^2x\le n$, which can not be bounded by $\epsilon \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ does not exist. But the limit actually exists. How can I write a formal proof for $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ x=0$,

$$f_n(0)=0  \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(0)=0=f(0)$$

For $x>0$ and $n $ great enough, 
$$n\ge \lfloor \frac 1x \rfloor +1,$$
we will have $$\frac 1n < x$$
and
$$f_n(x)=0$$

So,

Given $x\in (0,1] $ and $ \epsilon>0$

there exists $ N=\lfloor \frac 1x \rfloor +1 $ such that

$$(\forall n\ge N )\;\;\;  |f_n(x)-0|=0<\epsilon$$

Thus $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=0$.

We conclude that

the sequence is pointwise convergent to the zero function $ f $  at $[0,1]$.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot.  And here I was applying limit definition on other definitions of $f_n(x)$., on $2n^2x$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

The given formulas obscure what's going on. It's really easier than that. Here it is in a general form: Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ such that i)$f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ and ii) for each $n,$ $f_n=0$ on $[1/n,1].$ Then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise everywhere on $[0,1].$